# Only show WordPress 'standard' post format on template?

Tags: wordpress

I recently added post formats to my WordPress theme - on the blog page its fine as they are all styled accordingly. However on my home page template I only want to show 'standard' posts formats (no links, galleries, audio, video etc.).

In my theme options I can decide how many posts to display on the front page which is what 'dft_recent_number' is for.

Does anybody know how I can change the code below to exclude all but 'standard' post formats?

```
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query();
    $query->query('posts_per_page='.get_option('dft_recent_number'));

    //Get the total amount of posts
$post_count = $query->post_count;

    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 

 ?>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) does not seem to have a straightforward parameter for `post_format`.

From my quick research it appears that post formats are related through taxonomies. So, **theoretically**, using the taxonomy parameters *should* work.

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'post-format-standard',
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**Note:** you'll need to update the taxonomy names and slugs for your blog. This should be the names you set in your functions.php file.

Comment: That put me on the right direction Jason, thanks!

I used the 'Not In' to remove the formats I didn't want e.g

    `$args = array(
 'showposts' => $number,
 'tax_query' => array(
   array( 'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array('post-format-video','post-format-quote','post-format-link','post-format-audio'),
      'operator' => 'NOT IN'
      )
   )
 );
 query_posts( $args );`

Answer (score 4):

```
// there's no post-format-standard so you should write it like this to exclude all other postpformats
array(
'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => array('post-format-quote','post-format-audio','post-format-gallery','post-format-image','post-format-link','post-format-video'),
'operator' => 'NOT IN'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that's old, but I was facing the same issue and even though I've found a solution I wondered what other have done to "fix" that.

I think a more scalable solution could be something like that:

```
$post_formats = get_theme_support( 'post-formats' );

$tax_query = false;
if ( $post_formats ) {
    $tax_query = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $post_formats[0],
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    );
}

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'orderby'   => 'date',
    'tax_query' => $tax_query
);
```

This would exclude the post formats that have been enabled and also will work in case WP will add more post formats (or add the ability to add more).